# Python Tkinter GUI, navigate menus using keyboard only

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple menu using Tkinter. It has 4 buttons, three of which open a new menu. I'd like the menu to be navigated using only the keyboard (i.e the directional buttons and return key). Using both mouse and keyboard would also be acceptable (i.e being able to use either mouse or keyboard to navigate).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Tkinter has the ability to use the keyboard built-in. There isn't much extra you need to do. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Learn about binding key events to widgets, perhaps from chanper 54 of http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html.

Comment: I've built the buttons and main frame (the buttons have a proxy function for now). However while I can press the buttons using the mouse, I don't know how to implement navigation using only the keyboard. Also thanks Terry, I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: The default bindings let you use tab key to move focus between widgets in the order they were created. If a button has focus, the space bar will click the button.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I just had a few questions: Can you change the default focus to the buttons when the program runs (or is it as simple as having the program press tab when it initiates?). Second, I noticed that you have to press tab to cycle through the buttons, can you make it so that the directional buttons are used instead? Finally (this may be stretching the bounds of the question a bit) is it possible to use a cursor (e.g a small arrow) to indicate the current focus, instead of the highlighted border? Thanks again!